# Growth in loops vs. growth in groups

Tags: group-theory, associativity

Let $s_1,\ldots,s_k $ are elements of $G$. Let $\langle s_1,\ldots, s_k \rangle$ be the set of elements generated by $\{s_1,\ldots,s_k\}$. Let $s_{k+1} \notin \langle s_1,\ldots, s_k \rangle$. Then it is a well known fact that

$$\langle s_1,\ldots,s_k \rangle \le 2\langle s_1,\ldots,s_{k+1} \rangle$$

The above hold in case of a group. Let $G$ be a group without associativity(loop). Is this still true? In other words do we need associativity to prove the above inequality?

Comment: "group without associativity". You mean loops?

Comment: @Arturo Magidin Yes.

Comment: Then how about saying "loop"?

Comment: The fact follows from Lagrange's Theorem, but Lagrange's Theorem does not, in general, hold for loops. I don't know any examples off hand, but it seems like you should be able to get a "large" subloops so that this does not hold.